# Quirk with custom Layout Behavior when updating to Support Library 24

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout

In the last couple of project I've worked on I always had a custom layout behavior for a Button to mimick the animation a FloatingButton makes when a Snackbar is shown. The code I used is:

```
public class BehaviorButton extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<Button> {

    public BehaviorButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {}

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, Button child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, Button child, View dependency) {
        float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        child.setTranslationY(translationY);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then "bind" this class to the Button through xml.

```
app:layout_behavior=".BehaviorButton"
```

Nothing special. **The problem**: When I updated the support libraries from 23.4.0 to 24 this functionality disappeared. My question is: **How am I supposed to implement such behavior in support library 24?**

[image: Correct behavior with 23.4.0]

In the following gif you can see how there is NO Button. When I add the `layout_behavior` it "loses" its postion.

[image: Button disappear!!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the dependency is `SnackbarLayout` and only then translate the button.

```
@Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, Button child, View dependency) {
      if(dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout){
        float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        child.setTranslationY(translationY);
        return true;
       }
      return false;
    }
```